# NSURLSession priority

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm trying to port my old code for loading files from `NSOperationQueue` to `NSURLSession`. Almost everything is alright but I can't find how to set priority for loading different tasks. Does anybody know if `NSURLSession` supports prioritising at all? And if yes could you show me how, please?

Thanks in advance!

Rost

Comment: The only prioritisation I've seen comes from [networkServiceType](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/networkServiceType).

Comment: Never seen/heard of prioritizing with NSURLSession- I think you should schedule the taskQueue with short sets of tasks instead of loading the whole bunch.

Comment: Seems that the priorities are per task, not session.
BTW, I believe you could use HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost to prioritize your session.

Answer (score 11):

There is a property on `NSURLSessionTask`

```
@property float priority NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

Its description says

> - Sets a scaling factor for the priority of the task. The scaling factor is a   value between 0.0 and 1.0 (inclusive), where 0.0 is
>     considered the lowest priority and 1.0 is considered the highest.
> - The priority is a hint and not a hard requirement of task performance. The   priority of a task may be changed using this API
>     at any time, but not all  protocols support this; in these cases,
>     the last priority that took effect will be used. If no
>     priority is specified, the task will operate with the default priority
> - as defined by the constant NSURLSessionTaskPriorityDefault. Two additional  priority levels are provided:
>     NSURLSessionTaskPriorityLow and NSURLSessionTaskPriorityHigh, but
>     use is not restricted to these.

I use it between a downloadTask and dataTask that could trigger simultaneously in our app and the dataTask waits for the download forever. But this fixes the issue

```
dataTask.priority = NSURLSessionTaskPriorityHigh;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is available yet in iOS 8, but I found these lines in NSURLSession.h file

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const float NSURLSessionTaskPriorityDefault NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const float NSURLSessionTaskPriorityLow NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const float NSURLSessionTaskPriorityHigh NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

The apple iOS 8.1 release note is suggesting that these will be available in 8.1 though.

Comment: These are supposed to be available in iOS 8 and later, but it appears there is a bug when using these in an optimized build. 
https://openradar.appspot.com/23956486